# Jooq connection lifecycle

Tags: jooq

I am evaluating Jooq and I would like to confirm my understanding about the JDBC connection lifecycle.

I am using a connection pool (Hikari) and I configure a DSLContext using the datasource.

As I understand it:

1. I am safe to create one DSLContext that I can reuse across my application in many threads? Is there any negative to doing this provided I don't modify the config? Contention etc?
2. Each time I do a database access, does Jooq obtain a connection from the pool, do the DB access and then commit and release it? Eg:

```
Result<Record> result = context.select().from(AUTHOR).fetch();
Result<Record> otherResult = context.select().from(BOOKS).fetch();
```

Each of these queries would obtain and release a new connection from the pool?

3. When using the transaction API like this:

```
context.transaction(ctx -> {
        DSLContext trans = DSL.using(ctx);
   ...
});
```

A connection would be obtained from the pool and reused for all accesses using the `trans` context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am safe to create one DSLContext that I can reuse across my application in many threads?

Yes, you can, provided that after initialisation, you don't modify your `Configuration` and its components anymore, e.g. `Settings`.

> Is there any negative to doing this provided I don't modify the config? Contention etc?

Au contraire, that's the recommended way of using a `DSLContext`. By reusing it, you will benefit from caching, e.g. for reflection if you're using `Result.into(MyDto.class)` methods, etc.

> Each time I do a database access, does Jooq obtain a connection from the pool, do the DB access and then commit and release it?

Yes, that's how it works, if your `DataSource` is backed by a pool. Of course, the pool is free to provide jOOQ with the same connection every time, depending on transactional contexts that are governed outside of jOOQ. jOOQ doesn't care.

> When using the transaction API like this: [...] A connection would be obtained from the pool and reused for all accesses using the trans context?

The `transaction()` method obtains a connection and keeps it for the duration of the `TransactionalRunnable` that you pass to it (i.e. the lambda). Your nested `DSLContext trans` instance will now work with the "cached" `Connection`, and not obtain new connections from your `DataSource`.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies. Its good to have my understanding confirmed.

Comment: Somewhat off topic for this question, but I was also wondering, how do "select for update" type statements work with a connection pool? Do they only work within a transaction lambda, or does the same connection get kept around somehow after a "for update" clause?

Comment: @StephenODonnell: There's nothing special about the `FOR UPDATE` syntax from a jOOQ perspective... But I'll be happy to answer a new question if you have specific doubts